# Can't use alias and externals with Electrode custom webpack configuration

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux, alias, walmart-electrode

I am trying to customize the webpack configuration. I am using alias to shorten my URL declaration and externals for some cases such as: jQuery,...

However, when I import/require, node keeps telling me that "Cannot find module".

```
(node:9684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Cannot find module 'Component/home' 
(node:9684) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

my custom webpack configuration file

[image]

[image: import in my component]

Comment: Don't use images for code. It prevents people from being able to get to this question by searching. Please add your code to code blocks

Comment: Also how is your file structure? `../../../src/client/components` is quite a few folders back from your custom webpack config file. Are you sure you have the correct path?

Comment: @Thuan Nguyen did you ever find a way to use aliases with electrode?